# What is the difference between these two types of negation?

Tags: meaning, differences, prefixes

What is the difference between:-

> 1. Ali is rich,but he isn't happy.
> 2. Ali is rich, but he is unhappy.

Comment: You might want to ask questions like this one at the companion site for [ell.se]. If you're wondering about the difference between the two sites, I'd suggest starting [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722).

Comment: There's no real meaning difference between _-'nt happy_ (free _not_ is virtually always contracted with an auxiliary) and _unhappy_, except that _unhappy_ is usually used to characterize a distinct emotion, while _-'nt happy_, with the negation separated from the emotion, is more likely to refer to **any** reason for the absence of happiness, like a particular emotion overwhelming it. E.g, _He's not happy; he's mad_ does not necessarily mean that he is unhappy. But _?He's unhappy; he's mad_ doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to get into immense interpretation, here's the difference:

**Please note: This is way over-analytical, and for all intent and purpose there really is no difference - I'm treating this more like a logic exercise.**

### Ali is rich, but he isn't happy.

Ali is rich, but he may be upset, disappointed, or anything other than happy. He might not feel any emotion at all - Ali could be a psychopath unable to feel emotion, utterly indifferent to his wealth.

He could also be enraged, fuming and miserable; violently angry. When saying you're "not happy" 99% of people are saying they're mad.

More of the details about Alis' mood are left to the context of adjoining sentences.

### Ali is rich, but he is unhappy.

Ali is rich, and he's feeling something other than happiness. The main difference is that he is feeling *something*, an emotion counter to happiness. It may be malcontent, anger or disappointment, but he's not feeling nothing.

He's much more likely to be feeling malcontent in this variant. When people say they're "unhappy" this way, they tend to mean they're displeased or unsatisfied.

---

If I was being called into my boss's office and they said he "isn't happy", I'd probably be fairly afraid  of something I screwed up. If I was called into the office because the boss was "unhappy" I'd be thinking that my work wasn't up to standard - but not actively bad.